iOS - How to Implement a Customizable Tab Bar with Transparent Overlay in SwiftUI?
I'm trying to create a custom tab bar in SwiftUI similar to the one in the Microsoft Teams app iOS. Specifically, I need the following functionality:
When the "More" tab item is pressed, a transparent overlay view should open, displaying additional options.
Selecting any item in this overlay should set it as the root view for the "More" tab.
I've attached a screenshot for reference.


struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = 0
    @State private var showMoreOptions = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                Text("Teams").tabItem { Label("Teams", systemImage: "person.3") }.tag(0)
                Text("Chat").tabItem { Label("Chat", systemImage: "message") }.tag(1)
                Text("Calendar").tabItem { Label("Calendar", systemImage: "calendar") }.tag(2)
                Text("Calls").tabItem { Label("Calls", systemImage: "phone") }.tag(3)
                Text("More").tabItem { Label("More", systemImage: "ellipsis") }
                    .tag(4)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        showMoreOptions.toggle()
                    }
            }

            if showMoreOptions {
                TransparentOverlayView()
            }
        }
    }
}

i stuck here to implement the same logic which is there in teams app.
ex: when I press Updates in more bottom sheet it should set rootview of the more tab.
Any help or suggestions to implement this in SwiftUI would be greatly appreciated!

I did create my own custom Tabbar using UIKit, but this time I want to create it in SwiftUI, Also I am new to SwiftUI hence I posted here

Yes I am open to create a new custom swiftui behaviour, if you have any reference please share

Here is a starting point, from which you can add your own styling/layout etc. This just uses a HStack for the bottom tab bar, and shows the "more" tabs in a Grid with 4 tabs per row.
struct CustomTabView<Content: View, Selection: Hashable>: View {
    
    @Binding var selectedTab: Selection
    
    @ViewBuilder let content: () -> Content
    
    // The maximum number of tabs that can be shown at the bottom (including "More")
    let maxTabsShown = 5
    
    @State private var moreShown = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            ExtractMulti(content) { views in
                // The current tab
                ForEach(views) { view in
                    // Instead of this 'if', use .opacity(view.id(as: Selection.self) == selectedTab ? 1 : 0)
                    // to control visibility if you want to preserve the state in each tab (e.g. scroll offset)
                    if view.id(as: Selection.self) == selectedTab {
                        view
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    }
                }
                
                // The sheet for selecting the extra tabs
                if moreShown {
                    Color.black.opacity(0.7)
                        .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            moreShown = false
                        }
                        .transition(.opacity)
                    
                    // Here I've laid the extra tabs in a grid
                    Grid(horizontalSpacing: 30, verticalSpacing: 30) {
                        let hiddenTabs = views.dropFirst(maxTabsShown - 1)
                        let viewRows = hiddenTabs.chunks(ofCount: 4)
                        
                        ForEach(viewRows.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                            let row = viewRows[i]
                            GridRow {
                                ForEach(row) { view in
                                    Button {
                                        if let selection = view.id(as: Selection.self) {
                                            selectedTab = selection
                                            moreShown = false
                                        }
                                    } label: {
                                        if let label = view[CustomTabItemTrait.self] {
                                            label
                                        } else {
                                            Text("Unnamed")
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(.background, in: UnevenRoundedRectangle(topLeadingRadius: 10, topTrailingRadius: 10))
                    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom).combined(with: .opacity))
                }
                Divider()
            }
        }
        // The bottom tab bar
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                ExtractMulti(content) { views in
                    let shownTabs = 
                        views.count <= maxTabsShown ?
                            views.prefix(maxTabsShown) :
                            views.prefix(maxTabsShown - 1)
                    
                    ForEach(shownTabs) { view in
                        Group {
                            if let label = view[CustomTabItemTrait.self] {
                                label
                            } else {
                                Text("Unnamed")
                            }
                        }
                        .onTapGesture {
                            if let selection = view.id(as: Selection.self) {
                                selectedTab = selection
                                moreShown = false
                            }
                        }
                        .foregroundStyle(
                            view.id(as: Selection.self) == selectedTab ?
                                AnyShapeStyle(Color.accentColor) : AnyShapeStyle(.opacity(1))
                        )
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    
                    if views.count > maxTabsShown {
                        Label("More", systemImage: "ellipsis")
                            .onTapGesture {
                                moreShown.toggle()
                            }
                            .foregroundStyle(
                                shownTabs.contains(where: { $0.id(as: Selection.self) == selectedTab }) ?
                                    AnyShapeStyle(.opacity(1)) : AnyShapeStyle(Color.accentColor)
                            )
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .animation(.default, value: moreShown)
    }
}

extension View {
    func customTabItem<Content: View>(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) -> some View {
        _trait(CustomTabItemTrait.self, AnyView(content()))
    }
}

struct CustomTabItemTrait: _ViewTraitKey {
    static let defaultValue: AnyView? = nil
}

This depends on ExtractMulti from View Extractor. It's not difficult to implement yourself if you don't want to add a dependency:
// From View Extractor - https://github.com/GeorgeElsham/ViewExtractor
public struct ExtractMulti<Content: View, ViewsContent: View>: View {
    let content: () -> Content
    let views: (Views) -> ViewsContent

    public init(_ content: Content, @ViewBuilder views: @escaping (Views) -> ViewsContent) {
        self.content = { content }
        self.views = views
    }

    public init(@ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> Content, @ViewBuilder views: @escaping (Views) -> ViewsContent) {
        self.content = content
        self.views = views
    }

    public var body: some View {
        _VariadicView.Tree(
            MultiViewRoot(views: views),
            content: content
        )
    }
}

fileprivate struct MultiViewRoot<Content: View>: _VariadicView_MultiViewRoot {
    let views: (Views) -> Content

    func body(children: Views) -> some View {
        views(children)
    }
}

public typealias Views = _VariadicView.Children

I have also used chunks(ofCount:) from Swift Algorithms. Again, this is something easy enough to implement yourself if you don't want to add a dependency.

When using this, remember to use customTabItem instead of the built-in tabItem, and id instead of tag to tag each tab.
Example usage:
@State var selectedTab = 0

var body: some View {
    CustomTabView(selectedTab: $selectedTab) {
        ForEach(0..<10) { i in
            Text("Tab \(i)")
                .customTabItem {
                    Label("\(i)", systemImage: "0\(i).circle")
                }
                .id(i)
        }
    }
}




Let us continue this discussion in chat.

when I select any tab item  it should close more sheet if it's already open. can you please tell me where that changes should be done here?

yes it works. when the sheet presents it shouldn't placed on the navigationbar view can you please tell me the way to show this?

in my case the sheet should present on top of the navigationbar. when i add the navigation bar in this code it just overlayed inside the view alone. can you please tell me the way to show this?

@Vignesh I cannot reproduce that. The Color.black.opacity(0.7) covers the navigation bar as expected because of .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top). And frankly, you are being quite annoying. Please make an effort yourself and take some time to read and understand what the code does. Please post a new question with a [mcve] if you are still stuck.

I am sure I will do the rest of the things. Thank you.

And please suggest some basic packages required to build a SwiftUI app, or anything you commonly use in SwiftUI development. This isn't related to the question; I'm just asking for suggestions.

I am not sure why you have deleted comments.

@Vignesh I deleted them because they are no longer needed. In fact you should delete your comments too. See the "When should comments be deleted?" section in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19757/302707

okay now I understand that

if you have some basic required libraries for learning aspects please share, better I will ask a question and tag you you can answer.

Sweeper: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78848737/swifui-recommended-libraries-packages-for-swiftui-app-development
